# Include multiple file extensions in ant

Tags: java, ant

I am having an Problem with an Ant build file. The whole configuration is legacy and I am not really familiar with ant, so I tried the ant manual and searching the interwebs but I still have no satisfying answer. I have this snippet:

```
        <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/${ivy.module}.jar">
            <fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}"/>
            <restrict>
                <name name="**/*.class"/>
                <archives>
                    <zips>
                        <fileset dir="${build.lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
                    </zips>
                </archives>
            </restrict>
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Manifest-Version" value="1.0"/>
                <attribute name="Created-By" value="${version} (${verndor.name})"/>
                <attribute name="Client-Version" value="${version}"/>
                <attribute name="Build-Number" value="${custom.build-number}"/>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
```

I also want to include a "*.so" file (to use with JNI), instead of just .class files from the extracted archives. What is the best way to do that? As I said the ant manual is rather vague.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The [FileSet documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) states that the `includes` attribute contains “comma- or space-separated list of patterns of files that must be included.” Doesn’t seem vague to me at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am not talking about that include part. afaik the include statement is, for selecting all the .jar files,
but that as I see it, the <name name="**/*.class"/> tag is actually used for filtering all the .class files from the jars to zip into the new jar and here I don't know how to change the filter. I already tried changing the name tag like so : <name name="**/*.class **/*.so"/> but then everything from those jars is excluded.

Comment: My mistake, I misread.

Answer (score 0):

The [<restrict> documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#restrict) lists possible nested selectors.  You can use `<or>` to specify multiple patterns:

```
<restrict>
    <or>
        <name name="*.class"/>
        <name name="path/to/libsomething.so"/>
    </or>
```